# Python not returning variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to return a variable (list)  in python but it does not allows me to return it. Instead it goes into except block and returns somethhing else.

The code is like this: Initially I'm getting `period_value(datetime)`, `search_name(location name)` and `time_period(day,week,month,year)` via Ajax calls. If its day, then its work fine, but in other cases(week,month,year) the result variable does gives me satisfied data but it does not returns the data and instead goes into except and returns something else. This seems to be a weird problem. Kindly check where I'm going wrong?

```
if request.POST.has_key('period_val') or request.POST.has_key('search_name'):
    try : period_val = request.POST['period_val']
    except : period_val = datetime.datetime.strftime((datetime.date.today()), '%m/%d/%Y')

    try: time_period = request.POST['time_period']
    except : time_period = 'day'

    try : search_name = request.POST['search_name']
    except : search_name = ""

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(get_widgets_data(request,period_val,time_period,search_name)), mimetype = "application/json")
```

**get_widgets_data functions**

```
def get_widgets_data(request,period_val,time_period,search_name):

    if time_period == 'day':
        file_name = datetime.datetime.strptime(period_val, '%m/%d/%Y')
        current_file_name = file_name.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.json")
        yester_date = file_name - timedelta(days = 1)
        yester_file_name = yester_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d.json")

    elif time_period == 'week':
        file_name = str(period_val).split(", ")
        current_file_name = file_name[1] + "-w" + file_name[0].split(" ")[0]+".json"

        if (int(file_name[0].split(" ")[0]) - 1) <= 0:
            year = int(file_name[1]) - 1 
            week = datetime.date(year,12,31).isocalendar()[-1]
            yester_file_name = file_name[1] + "-w" + file_name[0]+".json"
        else :
            yester_file_name = file_name[1] + "-w" + str(int(file_name[0].split(" ")[0]) - 1)+".json"

    elif time_period == 'month':
        file_name = datetime.datetime.strptime(period_val, '%B, %Y')
        current_file_name = file_name.strftime("%Y-%m.json")
        yester_month = int((current_file_name.split(".")[0]).split("-")[1]) - 1
        yester_year = int((current_file_name.split(".")[0]).split("-")[0])

        if yester_month == 0:
            yester_year = yester_year - 1
            yester_month = 12

        yester_file_name = str(yester_year) + "-" + str(yester_month) + ".json"

    elif time_period == 'year':
        file_name = datetime.datetime.strptime(period_val, '%Y')
        current_file_name = file_name.strftime("%Y.json")
        yester_file_name = str(int(period_val)-1) + ".json"

    with open( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../../../service/report/data/processed/Akamai/energy_meter/',current_file_name)) as file_handler:
        current_file_content = json.load(file_handler)
    file_handler.close()

    user_level_mapping = UserLevelMapping.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    level = (user_level_mapping[0].level_id).split(':')[0]
    l_id = (user_level_mapping[0].level_id).split(':')[1]

    try : # try if this file exists or not else goes into except.
        with open( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../../../service/report/data/processed/Akamai/energy_meter/',yester_file_name)) as file_handler:
            yester_file_content = json.load(file_handler)
        file_handler.close()

        device_level_mapping_values = device_level_mapping_func(level,l_id)
        yester_time = list()
        yester_file_datetime = yester_file_content["device"].keys()
        yester_total = 0.0

        for time in yester_file_datetime:
            yester_time.append(time.split(" ")[1])

        for date_time in current_file_content["device"].keys():
            time = date_time.split(" ")[1]
            if time in yester_time:
                for device in device_level_mapping_values:
                    yester_total += float(yester_file_content["device"][date_time][str(device)])            

        current_total = float(current_file_content['total']['levels']['level'+str(level)][str(l_id)])
        baseline_energy_yester = (yester_total) - current_total
        results = (current_total,baseline_energy_yester)
        print results # prints(123,345) but does not returns. instead goes into except for week,month and year and returns (123,Nan)
        return results

    except: 

        current_total = float(current_file_content['total']['levels']['level'+str(level)][str(l_id)])
        baseline_energy_yester = "NaN"
        results = (current_total,baseline_energy_yester)
        return results
```

Comment: Which exception is being returned? Also, can you add what your `request.POST.has_key`'s look like on the failure?

Comment: How can I check which exception is being returned?

Comment: @prafulbagai, the simplest way to do that is to omit the `try:` and `except:`, leaving only the "normal"/baseline behavior (remember to outdent the original `try` block and to delete the `except` block.)

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks @BrianCain

Answer (score 1):

Using `except` without identifying the types you're catching is a dangerous antipattern.  If the code in the `try` block encountered a `KeyboardInterrupt`, `NameError`, `ImportError` or `IOError`, is it really safe to assume that it's safe to continue and the recovery is simply to make sure that '`search_name`' is empty?

```
try : search_name = request.POST['search_name']
except : search_name = ""
```

As an aside, you can ask a `dict` to return a default if no matching key is defined:

```
search_name = request.POST.get('search_name', None)
```

---

> Instead it goes into except block and returns somethhing else.

In general if your code encounters an exception, something is "wrong".  Wrongness can vary, so it might not be devastating, but if you're not certain which exception is occurring and why then it's best not to try to handle it at all.  Let it fly all the way up the stack either to some code that has context to recover or gracefully fail, or better still in cases like this -- all the way up to the developer (you!) so you can address the failure in design/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To get value of a POST post data field try using

```
period_val = request.POST.get('period_val')
```

instead of

```
period_val = request.POST['period_val']
```

Comment: in your if try this

for x in request.POST:print x,'\t',request.POST.get(x)

Comment: Going into except block.

Comment: yaa I wrote it inside the if block only.